# Directory with pdf-file rename with array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, rename

I’m stuck renaming files.

I have a directory with pdf-files and I want to rename them automatically.
I read a CSV-file and show it in a datagrid with C#.
First column is the old filename and second is the new filename.

The old filenames have numbers before .pdf
The new filenames have numbers, letters and equel signes in the names before .pdf

I tired several code examples but the don't work for me. I’m a newbe. Below the code for creating the datagrid (array). How do I use the rows of the array to search fort he old name and rename it with the new name?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace VerplaatsenEnHernoemen
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        DataGridView my_datagridview = new DataGridView();
        DataTable my_datatable = new DataTable();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Size = new Size(750, 500);
            my_datagridview.Size = new Size(600, 400);
            my_datagridview.Location = new Point(5, 5);

            string[] raw_text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\\names.csv");
            string[] data_col = null;
            int x = 0;
            foreach (string text_line in raw_text)
            {
                data_col = text_line.Split(';');
                    if  (x == 0)
                {
                    for (int i =0;i<=data_col.Count() -1; i++)
                    {
                        my_datatable.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
                    }
                    x++;
                }
                else
                {
                    my_datatable.Rows.Add(data_col);
                }
            }
            my_datagridview.DataSource = my_datatable;
            this.Controls.Add(my_datagridview);


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: at the moment this is only display code. should users be able to modify the new file names before renaming starts? you will have to define an event which starts the renaming process - on a per-row basis or with a button. how did the code examples you tried not work? exceptions, never executed, ...

Comment: Hi dlatikay. You are right! This is only displaying the data from D:\names.csv in a 2 column grid. I started coding the renaming but it didn't make any sence.

Comment: Hi dlatikay. You are right! This is only displaying the data from D:\names.csv in a 2 column grid.  There are no users, I just want to rename lots of files. on a per-row basis would be fine. I started coding the renaming but it didn't make any sence.

Comment: In this case it would be sufficient to have `File.Move(data_col[0],data_col[1]);` in the `else` block of the loop (for a cheap, non-interactive one-off solution, and assuming you have absolute paths in the csv)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I said: I'm a newbe. Is data_col[0] representing the column oldfilename and data_col[1] representing the newfilename column? the columns are descibed in names.csv in the first row. I have to do this with foreach I think.

Comment: yes. the logic with the variable x will already skip the header row, so doing the move=rename in the else is ok. make yourself familiar with the debugger and step through your code line by line. so you can see how split will place the first token in the array at index 0 etc...

Comment: Everytime I think I understand, I don't. So the array is already loaded and with File.Move(data_col[0],data_col[1]); in the else I can rename the files. But where do I point to the location of the pdf-files.

Comment: that's up to you to specify. you could require absolute paths in names.csv; you could assume the current or executable path, or that where names.csv resides. if you need to build a path from a directory and a file name, use `Path.Combine`.